# Why in my Linux, when current work directory is owned by root (e.g /usr/bin), then I cannot link any library while compiling c++?

Tags: c++, linux

If I write this code and saved as a.cpp at ~/Desktop

```cpp
#include <memory>
int main(){}
```

then input to bash:

```sh
cd /usr/bin
g++ -g ~/Desktop/a.cpp -o ~/Desktop/a
```

then the g++ will output plenty of messy code of errors.
I have found the reason is because it don't have authority to link XX.so library.

But if I add a 'sudo' , or set CWD to the path owned by user, g++ will work properly, as follows:

```sh
sudo g++ -g ~/Desktop/a.cpp -o ~/Desktop/a
```

or

```sh
cd ~/Desktop
g++ -g ~/Desktop/a.cpp -o ~/Desktop/a
```

Why do this happen? or how can I fix this?

Comment: Why the CWD can impact the compiling work?

Comment: When using clang++, it's same, output plenty of messy code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would consider a "fix", but you may want to try
     `g++ -g ~/Desktop/a.cpp -o ~/Desktop/a`
instead? I.e. not write output to a directory where you don't have the necessary rights.

Comment: This is standard unix behavior.  `/usr/bin` is read only unless you are root.   You can't copy files into that folder, much less have your output binaries go there.  `sudo` makes you root for the lifetime of the command

Comment: Sorry for that I left out the full path in the post, I'm not creating a file in /ust/bin, the actually command I typed in is g++ ~/Desktop/a.cpp -o ~/Desktop/a

Comment: And I found that it's not the authority of the path that mattered, because when CWD is / , g++ can work properly. but in /usr of /usr/bin it cannot.

Comment: I can't repro this: https://imgur.com/a/zVHoPDW

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to generate code directly in `/usr/bin`.

You generate your code in your user folder, maybe create a sub-directory called `cppwork` or something like that.

```
cd
mkdir cppwork
cd cppwork
g++ -g a.cpp -o a
```

Once you compiled in your directory, then you copy the file using `install` which will also take care of stripping the debug if any (i.e. the `-g` says to keep debug info—stripping is not mandatory).

```
sudo install -s a /usr/bin/a
```

As you can see, the place where I use `sudo` is with the `install` command.

That being said, I never use those directly. Now a day, I use `cmake` which means everything works *automatically*. But that would be a different discussion.

Comment: I'm sorry that I left out the full path in the question. The command I input to bash is correct, I'm not creating a file in /usr/bin, this is what I actually type in:

```
/usr/bin/g++ ~/Desktop/xx/xx.cpp -o ~/Desktop/xx/xx
```

Comment: @xxhxx, Oh! Then this probably doesn't apply directly, indeed. The `cd /usr/bin` would not be useful. Note that this is something you could have edited in your question to make it clear that you weren't trying to write to `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for every one. I have found the reason. It's because there is an executable program named 'array' in /usr/bin. And when CWD is /usr/bin, the compiler regard this 'array' as the c++ header `<array>`, so compiling error.
Then I need to find out why the compiler includes /usr/bin by mistake.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. By default the compiler first tries `./` as the `#include` search path.